# Share internet from HOST to PC via router

Tags: server, ethernet, proxy, lan, router

I have HOST, which is connected to WAN and router;
Also I have a PC, that connected to router;
I can ssh from HOST to PC and vice versa;
Both are ubuntu 20;

How can I make internet availability on PC?
Proxy servers or what?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: Does "Ubuntu 20" mean Ubuntu Core 20 (server)? Or does it mean Ubuntu 20.04 Server? Or does it mean Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop? The simplest answer is to rearrange the cables so WAN runs to router instead of HOST. That's what routers are for.

Comment: enable port fwd in router